# Is there a way to change the colour of Functions for C++ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, colors, formatting

So i am aware that in C# and Visual basic there is an enhanced syntax highlighter (Which i use)
I was wondering if there is a similar tool for other languages, primarily C++, in order to allow me to change the colour of various elements in VS, such as Functions.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change colors of individual language features in the `Environment > Fonts and Colors` dialog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2019 To specifically address your question "C++ Functions" is one of those features you can specify a color for

Comment: In Visual studio? In other IDEs? Generally, all "big" languages (and most smaller languages) have syntax highlighters...

Comment: @CoryKramer I see! I was using a Function that was part of another class being accessed with :: as my tester, so i didn't realise the formatting wasn't applied to it, as it is a member function, many thanks!